# How to LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE using @column with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I need to set color based on color code using @set on Load Data Local INFILE

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
        ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
        ESCAPED BY \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
        (Brand, @Color, @Year)
        SET
        Color = if (@Color = "1b"){ Color = "Blue" } else { Color = "Green" },
        Year = "2022"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the mysql style of the if clause

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
        ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
        ESCAPED BY \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
        (Brand, @Color, @Year)
        SET
        Color = if (@Color = '1b',  'Blue' ,  'Green' ),
        Year = "2022"
```

For more option

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
        ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
        ESCAPED BY \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
        (Brand, @Color, @Year)
        SET
        Color = CASE @Color 
        WHEN '1b' THEN  'Blue' 
        WHEN '2b' THEN 'brown'
        ELSE  'Green' 
        END,
        Year = "2022"
```

Comment: How would handle if color 1b = Blue and Color 2b = Brown

Comment: you use case when see changed answer